# Setting encoding while reading file in sftp using paramiko

Tags: python, pandas, paramiko

I am new to the forum . I am trying to read a file(kept on sftp) using paramiko package. I need to set the encoding while reading the file but I am not sure if I see an option.Any ideas on how to achieve this.

Thanks,
A